# npm install error while following instructions from https://github.com/liferay/alloy-ui

Tags: json, node.js, github, gruntjs, alloy-ui

The following error appears while installing local dependencies by following the instructions from this [Github/Alloyui](https://github.com/liferay/alloy-ui) link.

I am using Windows 7 Os

```
C:\Users\Admin.HOME-PC>npm install 
npm ERR! install Couldn't read dependencies
npm ERR! Failed to parse json
npm ERR! Unexpected end of input
npm ERR! File: C:\Users\Admin.HOME-PC\package.json
npm ERR! Failed to parse package.json data.
npm ERR! package.json must be actual JSON, not just JavaScript.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! This is not a bug in npm.<br>
npm ERR! Tell the package author to fix their package.json file. JSON.parse

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nod
ejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! cwd C:\Users\Admin.HOME-PC
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.21
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.11
npm ERR! file C:\Users\Admin.HOME-PC\package.json
npm ERR! code EJSONPARSE
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Admin.HOME-PC\npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Can please some one say how to over come this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Regards, 
Dinesh M K

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to **use** AlloyUI in your project, download it from [Alloy website](http://alloyui.com) and include it in your app as explained.

If you want to **customize or play** with AlloyUI source, you have to follow the setup instructions on the Github repo. Make soure you've cloned the repository first, then `cd {cloned_repo}` and run `npm install` (and so on as described).

Answer (score 0):

CHeck your package.json file. It contain some error.

Comment: Hi Eugene, 
I am new to json. Now only I am installing the Nodejs by following the instructions in the given above github site. Can you please explain me how to do the same.